# increasing count in an array in Assembly 8086

Tags: arrays, assembly, count, x86-16, counting

```
freq dw 512 dup(0)
lea si, freq

;Now if I move a char 'a' into al and then do:

mov [si], al
```

will that put the letter 'a' into the first spot in the array? 
I am trying to have the ASCII number that corresponds with 'a' increase by 1, so at the 97 line in the array freq +1. How do I change my code to do this?

*basically I am trying to use one array to store the frequency count of all the chars I come across when going through a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will that put the letter 'a' into the first spot in the array?

Yes (in the lower byte of the first element actually, since `freq` is an array of words).

> I am trying to have the ASCII number that corresponds with 'a' increase by 1, so at the 97 line in the array freq +1.

```
mov bx,'a'*2
inc word ptr [bx+si]
```

Or if you had the character in `al`:

```
xor bh,bh   ; clear bh
mov bl,al
add bx,bx   ; scale index by 2
inc word ptr [bx+si]
```

If 80386 instructions are allowed you could replace `xor bh,bh` and `mov bl,al` with `movzx bx,al`.

Comment: Ok I understand you answer, for my question  I supplied the letter 'a' directly, however if I were to implement a loop where the next char is placed in the register al, this code wont be applicable. I want to do => mov bx, (ASCII code of the char in al)*2. Also why the *2? wouldnt that do a +1 to the 194th spot in the array instead of the 97th?

Comment: You've declared `freq` as an array of words (`dw`). So each element is 2 bytes, and the index therefore has to be scaled by 2. See my updated answer for how to do this if the character is in `al`.